# How to perform a ftp operation on airflow

Tags: ftp, airflow

I am required to perform an operation on airflow that performs a poke wait on a file on a ftp site, then bring in the file.

I am trying to locate an example ftp to local task.  I have found sftp, but the provider does not have a secure ftp url yet, so here I am.

My problem is I see a million philosophical discussions but no cookbook examples of ftp pull.  Can someone please point me to one so I can use it to figure it out on my end?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it with SFTPOperator? it uses SSH Hook, so I guess it should work. Can you give it a try ?

Comment: I was told SFTP Operator will not work in FTP scenerioes.